# ExpressionEngine safecracker append channel entries seleted items entry_id to URL

Tags: url, append, expressionengine, safecracker

I want to append entry_id came from a selection box (embedded) to a safecracker URL

This is the code:

```
{exp:safecracker channel="blending_log"  return="sthome/blending/ENTRY_ID" dynamic_title="     [selected_tea]_[organic_or_conventional][date_time][agent_number]"}
<h3>Select and enter data</h3>
{embed="stembeds/.blending_select_tea"}

{!--------Receive data to create value--------}
<input type="hidden" name="title" value="" />
<br /><br />
Organic Or Conventional:
 {field:org_con}

 Agent Number:
 {field:agent_number}

{!-----END Receive data to create lot number-------}
```

This is the embed:

```
<select name="selected_tea">
<option selected="selected" >Select a Tea</option>
{exp:channel:entries channel="tea_herbs" order_by="title" sort="asc"}

<option name={title} id={entry_id} value={url_title}>{title}</option>

{/exp:channel:entries} 

</select>
```

In embed line 4 I have id="{entry_id}

```
<option name={title} id={entry_id} value={url_title}>{title}</option>
```

I want to take entry id and append it to safecracker's URL like below:

```
{exp:safecracker channel="blending_log"  return="sthome/blending/ENTRY_ID/entry_id" dynamic_title="     [selected_tea]_[organic_or_conventional][date_time][agent_number]"}
```

Because I want to use entry_id in next page to **retrieve some data in tea_herbs channel using {last_segment}**

Is this possible ?

I read documents for safecracker and I tried entry_id = "{segment_....}" but it did not work.
May be I am using entry_id = "{segment_....}" wrong way.

Please help me to accomplish this task

Comment: FYI: The EE focused SE site is now in public beta if you want to post future EE questions there: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your SafeCracker tag, `ENTRY_ID` will be replaced with the actual entry ID of the new entry. So just use `return="sthome/blending/ENTRY_ID`. This will redirect you to **sthome/blending/45** (for example).

Then, use `entry_id="{segment_3}"` in your **sthome/blending** template - though if you're using a standard Channel Entries or Safecracker tag on that page, it should read the entry ID automatically (since its the third segment).

Comment: Thanks again Derek.  My issue is that I have to send safecracker form's entry_id and the entry id created by embed:  '{embed="stembeds/.blending_select_tea"}'   The emebed's code:

Comment: May be I did not explain well.  In embed {embed="stembeds/.blending_select_tea"} select a Tea type:  <option name={title} id={entry_id} value={url_title}>{title}</option>   With safecracker URL I want to append selected Tea's entry_id. Like return="sthome/blending/ENTRY_ID/(Tea_Entry_id  and then I want to use Tea Entry id to retrieve Tea channel's some data (data in a Matrix)  Please help.  Thank you

Comment: May be I did not explain well. In embed {embed="stembeds/.blending_select_tea"} select a Tea type: <option name={title} id={entry_id} value={url_title}>{title}</option> With safecracker URL I want to append selected Tea's entry_id. **Like return="sthome/blending/ENTRY_ID/(Tea_Entry_id and then I want to use Tea Entry id to retrieve Tea channel's some data (data in a Matrix)** Please help. Thank you

Comment: Dear Derek, I found the answer. I use Javascript to retrieve the entry_id and put into a hidden field.  I appreciate your kind help.  You are simply amazing.  I also want to be an expert like you.  Thanks again

Comment: Glad you sorted it ... you should direct future questions to the new [EE StackExchange site](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com) - there are dozens of experts there!